# C#: Code Optimization for Date Formatting

Tags: c#, date-formatting

Using C#, I am trying to populate a variable with a known filename + date.  The catch is that the date must always be the last day of the previous month. It must also have no slashes or hyphens, and the year must be two digits.  For example, if it is now November 27 2015, I need my filename to be:  Foobar_103115.txt

As a programmer who still has much to learn, I have written the clunky code below and it does achieve my desired result, even though it will obviously break after the end of this century. My code is written this way because I could not figure out a more direct syntax for getting the date I want, complete with the specified formatting.

My question is this:  What would be a more elegant and efficient way of recreating the below code?

I have commented all the code for any novice programmers who might be interested in this. I know the experts I'm asking for help from don't need it.

```
public void Main()
{
    String Filename
    DateTime date = DateTime.Today;

    var FirstDayOfThisMonth = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(DateTime.Today.Day - 1)); //Gets the FIRST DAY of each month
    var LastDayOfLastMonth = FirstDayOfThisMonth.AddDays(-1); //Subtracts one day from the first day of each month to give you the last day of the previous month

    String outputDate = LastDayOfLastMonth.ToShortDateString(); //Reformats a long date string to a shorter one like 01/01/2015
    var NewDate = outputDate.Replace("20", ""); //Gives me a two-digit year which will work until the end of the century
    var NewDate2 = NewDate.Replace("/", ""); //Replaces the slashes with nothing so the format looks this way: 103115 (instead of 10/31/15)

    Filename = "Foobar_" + NewDate2 + ".txt"; //concatenates my newly formatted date to the filename and assigns to the variable
```

Comment: do you know that the DateTime object has lots of powerful functionality for example you can get Current Month.. then can figure out what the current month - 1 is... from there you can get the total number of days in that month actually very simple

Comment: `var FirstDayOfThisMonth = 1;`

Comment: @MethodMan: Doing it that way is actually a lot more work than just subtracting one day from the first day of *this* month, which is really easy.

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree, I didn't know if the OP was familiar with the `AddDays(-1)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like you want something more like:

```
// Warning: you should think about time zones...
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime startOfMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1);
DateTime endOfPreviousMonth = startOfMonth.AddDays(-1);
string filename = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    "FooBar_{0:MMddyy}.txt", endOfPreviousMonth);
```

I definitely *wouldn't* use `ToShortDateString` here - you want a very specific format, so express it specifically. The results of `ToShortDateString` will vary based on the current thread's culture.

Also note how my code only evaluates `DateTime.Today` once - this is a good habit to get into, as otherwise if the clock "ticks" into the next day between two evaluations of `DateTime.Today`, your original code could give some pretty odd results.

Comment: Very nice!  Thank you. I changed it to {0:MMddyy} to match my format.

Comment: @Hotelsinger: Whoops, sorry - will fix my answer. I'd strongly encourage you to change the format to yyyyMMdd if you possibly can though, which is sortable...

Comment: I do appreciate that.  However my solution ultimately picks up an FTP file that is pre-named.  That is why I need that specific formatting.

Comment: @Hotelsinger: Well, now would be an excellent time to at least start planning how you can move to something more sensible (and less US-centric). You may need to use this code for the moment, but start thinking about what would be required to change...